# Using WKT in SLD

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, well-known-text

I have a Point geometry and need to draw some shape (a Polygon for now) when styling.

Lets say I have this SLD:

```
<Rule>
  <PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
      <Mark>
        <WellKnownName>wkt://POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))</WellKnownName>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#009900</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.4</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </Mark>
      <Rotation>0</Rotation>
    </Graphic>
  </PointSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

Having my map in EPSG:4326, what do "1" and "0" in the Polygon definition rules mean?

I can see little squares in my map indeed, but don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general SLD uses pixels for it's measurements, you can switch to [ground units](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/uom.html?highlight=uom) by adding a parameter `uom` to the `Symbolizer`:

```
<PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. What about the reference point to start draw? I mean... 0,0 is where from the given Point geometry corrdinates?

Comment: ... and the draw direction ( from 0,0 the pen goes to where to reach 1,0 ? )

Comment: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/style/markwkt/WKTMarkFactory.java creates a https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/geometry/jts/LiteShape.java but I can't tell where it starts, I think you'll need to experiment

Comment: Ok. It is drawed counterclockwise (Lon,Lat): ```POLYGON ((0 0, ${width} 0, ${width} ${length}, 0 ${length}, 0 0))``` where 0,0 is the Point geometry coordinates.

Comment: feel free to update the documentation with that information

Comment: Ian, I'm still in trouble, but I've started a new question... I can't go deeper to learn ```WKTMarkFactory``` for now. Can you please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456930/wkt-not-using-metre-as-measure-unit-in-sld